# Azure Blob upload error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I m in trouble. I have build an application that can upload files on Azure via the SDK Azure.Storage.Blobs.
My application is a standalone DLL that can be caught by a windows running programm which can start the process by a thread using the reflexion.
When I test my application via a Winform application Test, everything is perfect: I can create my Blob Container, connect to azure and upload my Blobs.

But when my DLL is started by another program, I have an error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of his dependancies on Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient (String connectionString, BlobClientOptions options)   à AzureCloud.GetBlobContainer(String pBlocContainer)
The error pop on the creation of the BlobServiceClient.

I have checked that all my dll and dependancies are in "Copy Local" to "True". I tried to install the plugin on my other application that start my dll. Nothing works and I cannot find any working solution.
Below is the code to upload the file:

```
 public async Task<string> UploadFile(FileInfo file, string pBlocContainer)
    {
        try
        {
            var documentName = file.Name;

            var container = GetBlobContainer(pBlocContainer);
            BlobClient blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient(documentName);

            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file.FullName))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadAsync(fileStream);
            }
            return blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message + e.InnerException);
        }
    }
 public static BlobContainerClient GetBlobContainer(string pBlocContainer)
    {
        // Pull these from config
        var blobStorageConnectionString = mConnectionString; 
        var blobStorageContainerName = pBlocContainer; 

        // Create blob client and return reference to the container
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobStorageConnectionString);
        BlobContainerClient container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobStorageContainerName);
        return container;

    }
```

I use the nuget Azure.Core 1.8.1

Thanks by advance for your help. If need other informations tell me..

Comment: For information I have also tried to copy the dll in toruble in my SysWow64 and my System32 folder. But it doesn't work better....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Anyone has this problem I Managed to solve it by writting the assemblies declaration and redirection of Azure in the principal process .config file, even if this process have nothing to do with it ...